# Directly, run source code in Eclipse is OK. Why the Jar file will stop run and no exception show in console?

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I have tried very hard to find the answer in Stackoverflow and Google. I also try many ways to test my program but failed.
My problem is as below:
I have try to coding a server program in PC side and communicate with client in another machine. I can run the whole program in Eclipse IDE and no problem. Very strangely, I can not run the Jar file in the same PC.

Due to no error message, I guess the process of packing Jar file maybe is the key point. I try to test all possible way to export the jar file and also modify the different kind MENIFEST file to test the program.

Below is the program:

```
package idv.xml.serverclient;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError;

import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;
//import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Server1 extends Thread {

    private Socket mySocket;
    private ServerSocket myServer;
    private int intPort;
    private ReadFile readFile;
    private ReadData ReadData;
    private String isContinue = "0";
    WriteFile wftolog = new WriteFile();

    public Server1() {
        // 預設建構子
    }

    public Server1(int intPort) {
        // super();
        this.intPort = intPort;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.run();
        while (true) {
            readFile = new ReadFile();

            try {
                myServer = new ServerSocket(intPort);
                System.out.println("Server started at port:" + intPort);
                // 等待Client的連接

                System.out.println("Waiting for Client Connet.....");
                wftolog.addLog("Waiting for Client Connet.....");
                // 設置監聽器等待client的連線
                mySocket = myServer.accept();

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try {
                            SimpleAttributeSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
                            StyleConstants.setForeground(keyWord, Color.RED);
                            StyleConstants.setBackground(keyWord, Color.YELLOW);
                            StyleConstants.setBold(keyWord, true);
                            HMI_Window.doc.insertString(0, "工作中........\n", keyWord);

                        } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                });
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Accept Client " + mySocket);
            System.out.println("------Connection Created--------");
            wftolog.addLog("連線成功, 工作中........");
            if (ReadFile.isPTP == 0) {
                System.out.println("進去讀LIN資料串");
                readBufferLIN();
                wftolog.addLog("傳輸LIN資料成功。");
            } else {
                //確認是否是最後一個檔案
                if (ReadFile.fileCounter == (idv.xml.serverclient.ReadData.fileNumber)) {
                    isContinue = "1";
                }
                System.out.println("進去讀PTP資料串");
                readBufferPTP();
                wftolog.addLog("傳輸PTP資料成功。");
                System.out.println("readFile.fileCounter="+(ReadFile.fileCounter-1)+";readData.fileNumber="+(idv.xml.serverclient.ReadData.fileNumber - 1));
                if (ReadFile.fileCounter == (idv.xml.serverclient.ReadData.fileNumber)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            // 完成連線
            System.out.println("success");
            wftolog.addLog("完成資料傳輸");
        }
    }

    public void readBufferPTP() {

        // ----------- XML傳送資料 (JDOM)-----------
        try {
            // 生成Document物件
            Document docJDOM = new Document();
            XMLOutputter XMLOut = new XMLOutputter();
            // 生成XML字符串，即XML文件的内容，包含很多换行符
            String xmlString = XMLOut.outputString(docJDOM);
            xmlString = "<Sensor>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<Message>Example message</Message>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<Positions>"+ "\n"
                    + "<Current A1=\"" + readFile.A1[0] + "\"" + " " 
                    + "A2=\"" + readFile.A2[0] + "\"" + " " 
                    + "A3=\"" + readFile.A3[0] + "\"" + " " 
                    + "A4=\"" + readFile.A4[0] + "\"" + " " 
                    + "A5=\"" + readFile.A5[0] + "\"" + " " 
                    + "A6=\"" + readFile.A6[0] + "\"" + " " 
                    + "E1=\"" + readFile.E1[0] + "\"" + " "
                    + "E2=\"" + readFile.E2[0] + "\"" + " " 
                    + "E3=\"" + readFile.E3[0] + "\"" + " " 
                    + "E4=\"" + readFile.E4[0] + "\"" + " " 
                    + "E5=\"" + readFile.E5[0] + "\"" + " " 
                    + "E6=\"" + readFile.E6[0]+ "\""  + "/>" + "\n"
                    +   "<Before>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<X>0.9842</X>"+ "\n"
                    +   "</Before>"+ "\n"
                    +   "</Positions>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<Nmb>" + String.valueOf(readFile.lineNumber) + "</Nmb>" + "\n"
                    +   "<Status>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<IsActive>1</IsActive>"+ "\n"
                    +   "</Status>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<Read>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc1 X=\""+ReadData.x[0]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[0]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[0]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[0]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[0]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[0]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc2 X=\""+ReadData.x[1]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[1]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[1]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[1]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[1]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[1]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc3 X=\""+ReadData.x[2]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[2]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[2]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[2]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[2]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[2]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc4 X=\""+ReadData.x[3]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[3]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[3]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[3]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[3]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[3]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc5 X=\""+ReadData.x[4]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[4]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[4]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[4]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[4]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[4]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc6 X=\""+ReadData.x[5]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[5]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[5]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[5]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[5]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[5]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc7 X=\""+ReadData.x[6]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[6]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[6]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[6]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[6]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[6]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc8 X=\""+ReadData.x[7]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[7]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[7]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[7]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[7]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[7]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc9 X=\""+ReadData.x[8]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[8]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[8]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[8]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[8]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[8]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc10 X=\""+ReadData.x[9]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[9]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[9]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[9]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[9]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[9]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc11 X=\""+ReadData.x[10]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[10]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[10]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[10]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[10]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[10]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc12 X=\""+ReadData.x[11]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[11]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[11]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[11]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[11]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[11]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc13 X=\""+ReadData.x[12]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[12]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[12]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[12]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[12]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[12]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc14 X=\""+ReadData.x[13]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[13]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[13]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[13]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[13]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[13]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc15 X=\""+ReadData.x[14]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[14]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[14]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[14]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[14]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[14]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc16 X=\""+ReadData.x[15]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[15]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[15]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[15]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[15]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[15]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc17 X=\""+ReadData.x[16]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[16]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[16]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[16]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[16]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[16]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc18 X=\""+ReadData.x[17]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[17]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[17]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[17]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[17]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[17]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc19 X=\""+ReadData.x[18]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[18]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[18]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[18]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[18]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[18]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc20 X=\""+ReadData.x[19]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[19]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[19]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[19]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[19]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[19]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc21 X=\""+ReadData.x[20]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[20]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[20]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[20]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[20]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[20]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc22 X=\""+ReadData.x[21]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[21]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[21]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[21]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[21]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[21]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc23 X=\""+ReadData.x[22]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[22]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[22]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[22]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[22]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[22]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc24 X=\""+ReadData.x[23]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[23]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[23]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[23]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[23]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[23]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc25 X=\""+ReadData.x[24]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[24]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[24]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[24]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[24]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[24]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc26 X=\""+ReadData.x[25]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[25]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[25]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[25]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[25]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[25]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc27 X=\""+ReadData.x[26]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[26]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[26]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[26]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[26]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[26]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc28 X=\""+ReadData.x[27]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[27]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[27]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[27]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[27]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[27]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc29 X=\""+ReadData.x[28]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[28]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[28]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[28]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[28]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[28]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc30 X=\""+ReadData.x[29]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[29]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[29]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[29]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[29]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[29]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc31 X=\""+ReadData.x[30]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[30]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[30]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[30]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[30]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[30]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc32 X=\""+ReadData.x[31]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[31]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[31]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[31]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[31]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[31]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc33 X=\""+ReadData.x[32]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[32]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[32]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[32]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[32]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[32]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc34 X=\""+ReadData.x[33]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[33]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[33]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[33]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[33]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[33]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc35 X=\""+ReadData.x[34]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[34]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[34]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[34]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[34]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[34]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc36 X=\""+ReadData.x[35]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[35]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[35]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[35]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[35]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[35]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc37 X=\""+ReadData.x[36]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[36]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[36]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[36]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[36]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[36]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc38 X=\""+ReadData.x[37]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[37]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[37]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[37]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[37]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[37]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc39 X=\""+ReadData.x[38]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[38]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[38]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[38]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[38]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[38]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc40 X=\""+ReadData.x[39]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[39]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[39]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[39]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[39]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[39]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc41 X=\""+ReadData.x[40]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[40]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[40]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[40]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[40]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[40]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc42 X=\""+ReadData.x[41]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[41]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[41]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[41]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[41]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[41]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc43 X=\""+ReadData.x[42]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[42]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[42]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[42]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[42]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[42]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc44 X=\""+ReadData.x[43]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[43]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[43]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[43]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[43]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[43]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc45 X=\""+ReadData.x[44]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[44]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[44]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[44]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[44]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[44]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc46 X=\""+ReadData.x[45]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[45]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[45]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[45]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[45]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[45]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc47 X=\""+ReadData.x[46]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[46]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[46]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[46]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[46]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[46]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc48 X=\""+ReadData.x[47]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[47]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[47]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[47]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[47]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[47]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc49 X=\""+ReadData.x[48]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[48]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[48]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[48]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[48]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[48]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc50 X=\""+ReadData.x[49]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[49]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[49]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[49]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[49]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[49]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc51 X=\""+ReadData.x[50]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[50]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[50]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[50]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[50]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[50]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc52 X=\""+ReadData.x[51]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[51]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[51]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[51]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[51]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[51]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc53 X=\""+ReadData.x[52]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[52]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[52]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[52]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[52]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[52]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc54 X=\""+ReadData.x[53]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[53]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[53]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[53]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[53]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[53]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc55 X=\""+ReadData.x[54]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[54]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[54]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[54]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[54]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[54]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc56 X=\""+ReadData.x[55]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[55]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[55]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[55]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[55]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[55]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc57 X=\""+ReadData.x[56]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[56]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[56]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[56]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[56]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[56]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc58 X=\""+ReadData.x[57]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[57]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[57]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[57]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[57]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[57]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc59 X=\""+ReadData.x[58]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[58]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[58]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[58]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[58]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[58]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc60 X=\""+ReadData.x[59]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[59]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[59]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[59]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[59]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[59]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc61 X=\""+ReadData.x[60]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[60]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[60]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[60]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[60]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[60]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc62 X=\""+ReadData.x[61]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[61]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[61]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[61]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[61]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[61]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc63 X=\""+ReadData.x[62]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[62]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[62]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[62]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[62]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[62]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc64 X=\""+ReadData.x[63]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[63]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[63]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[63]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[63]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[63]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc65 X=\""+ReadData.x[64]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[64]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[64]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[64]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[64]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[64]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc66 X=\""+ReadData.x[65]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[65]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[65]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[65]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[65]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[65]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc67 X=\""+ReadData.x[66]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[66]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[66]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[66]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[66]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[66]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc68 X=\""+ReadData.x[67]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[67]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[67]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[67]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[67]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[67]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc69 X=\""+ReadData.x[68]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[68]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[68]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[68]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[68]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[68]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc70 X=\""+ReadData.x[69]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[69]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[69]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[69]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[69]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[69]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc71 X=\""+ReadData.x[70]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[70]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[70]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[70]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[70]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[70]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc72 X=\""+ReadData.x[71]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[71]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[71]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[71]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[71]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[71]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc73 X=\""+ReadData.x[72]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[72]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[72]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[72]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[72]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[72]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc74 X=\""+ReadData.x[73]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[73]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[73]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[73]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[73]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[73]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc75 X=\""+ReadData.x[74]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[74]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[74]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[74]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[74]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[74]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc76 X=\""+ReadData.x[75]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[75]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[75]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[75]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[75]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[75]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc77 X=\""+ReadData.x[76]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[76]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[76]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[76]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[76]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[76]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc78 X=\""+ReadData.x[77]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[77]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[77]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[77]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[77]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[77]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc79 X=\""+ReadData.x[78]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[78]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[78]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[78]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[78]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[78]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc80 X=\""+ReadData.x[79]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[79]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[79]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[79]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[79]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[79]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc81 X=\""+ReadData.x[80]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[80]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[80]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[80]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[80]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[80]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc82 X=\""+ReadData.x[81]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[81]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[81]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[81]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[81]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[81]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc83 X=\""+ReadData.x[82]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[82]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[82]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[82]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[82]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[82]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc84 X=\""+ReadData.x[83]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[83]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[83]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[83]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[83]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[83]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc85 X=\""+ReadData.x[84]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[84]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[84]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[84]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[84]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[84]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc86 X=\""+ReadData.x[85]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[85]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[85]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[85]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[85]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[85]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc87 X=\""+ReadData.x[86]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[86]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[86]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[86]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[86]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[86]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc88 X=\""+ReadData.x[87]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[87]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[87]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[87]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[87]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[87]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc89 X=\""+ReadData.x[88]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[88]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[88]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[88]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[88]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[88]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc90 X=\""+ReadData.x[89]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[89]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[89]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[89]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[89]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[89]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc91 X=\""+ReadData.x[90]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[90]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[90]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[90]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[90]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[90]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc92 X=\""+ReadData.x[91]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[91]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[91]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[91]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[91]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[91]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc93 X=\""+ReadData.x[92]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[92]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[92]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[92]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[92]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[92]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc94 X=\""+ReadData.x[93]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[93]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[93]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[93]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[93]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[93]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc95 X=\""+ReadData.x[94]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[94]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[94]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[94]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[94]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[94]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc96 X=\""+ReadData.x[95]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[95]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[95]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[95]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[95]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[95]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc97 X=\""+ReadData.x[96]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[96]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[96]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[96]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[96]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[96]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc98 X=\""+ReadData.x[97]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[97]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[97]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[97]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[97]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[97]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc99 X=\""+ReadData.x[98]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[98]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[98]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[98]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[98]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[98]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<xyzabc100 X=\""+ReadData.x[99]+"\" Y=\""+ReadData.y[99]+"\" Z=\""+ReadData.z[99]+"\" A=\""+ReadData.a[99]+"\" B=\""+ReadData.b[99]+"\" C=\""+ReadData.c[99]+"\"/>"+ "\n"
                    +   "</Read>"+ "\n"
                    +   "<Show error=\""+isContinue+"\" temp=\"9929\">Taginfo in attributes</Show>"+ "\n" 
                    +   "<Free>2912</Free>" + "\n" 
                    +   "</Sensor>";
            // 发送XML字符串
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(mySocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            out.println(xmlString);
            out.flush();

            // ------------ XML接收資料 (DOM)------------
            InputStream is = mySocket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String brString = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(brString);

            // 將STRING轉成NODE物件
            // 得到DocumentBuilderFactory的實體
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            // 得到DocumentBuilder的實體
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            // 得到Document的實體
            org.w3c.dom.Document document = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(brString.getBytes()));
            // 得到Element的實體, 此物件是實際的XML內容
            Element el = document.getDocumentElement();
            // 得到節點的資料
            NodeList nl = el.getElementsByTagName("LastPos");

            int nlInt = nl.getLength();
            System.out.println(nlInt);
            // X的值為LastPos的屬性所以要先getAttributes()
            String xPosString = nl.item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("X").getNodeValue();
            String yPosString = nl.item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("Y").getNodeValue();
            System.out.println("X=" + xPosString + " Y=" + yPosString);

        } catch (IOException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            wftolog.addLog("ERROR:傳輸PTP資料失敗。\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try {
                mySocket.close();
                myServer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                wftolog.addLog("ERROR:傳輸PTP資料成功, 關閉通道失敗。\n");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

The program will stop when call the method readBufferPTP(). In the method, the code can not be run inside the try catch and run the finally directly :

```
if (ReadFile.isPTP == 0) {
                System.out.println("進去讀LIN資料串");
                **readBufferLIN();**
                wftolog.addLog("傳輸LIN資料成功。");
            } else {
                //確認是否是最後一個檔案
                if (ReadFile.fileCounter == (idv.xml.serverclient.ReadData.fileNumber)) {
                    isContinue = "1";
                }
                System.out.println("進去讀PTP資料串");
                readBufferPTP();
                wftolog.addLog("傳輸PTP資料成功。");
                System.out.println("readFile.fileCounter="+(ReadFile.fileCounter-1)+";readData.fileNumber="+(idv.xml.serverclient.ReadData.fileNumber - 1));
                if (ReadFile.fileCounter == (idv.xml.serverclient.ReadData.fileNumber)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Due to no error message i have no any picture for you. I will upload the jar file.

Because I do not know how to upload the file, so I past the Manifest file as below:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: idv.xml.serverclient.HMI_Window
Class-Path: lib/jaxen-1.1.6.jar lib/jdom-2.0.6.jar lib/jdom-2.0.6-contrib.jar
  lib/jdom-2.0.6-javadoc.jar lib/jdom-2.0.6-junit.jar lib/jdom-2.0.6-sources.jar 
  lib/xerceslmpl.jar lib/xml-apis.jar lib/xalan/serializer-2.7.2.jar 
  lib/xalan/xalan-2.7.2.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solved the problem.
Because I know my code is no problem. The problem must be the jar export. So I tried to test every way to export the source code from Eclipse. The last way I do is export > Runnable JAR File > Extract required libraries into generated JAR.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have libraries included in your project that eclipse already has when building it therefor it can run the jar file, however when you try and run it in an explorer, those library files are no longer included.

If you compress all of your library files and original jar file into one Zip file and then converting it back to a jar file, your program should be executable from the file explorer.

You do this by extracting everything in your jar library files, and adding everything to one compressed file, the only manifest file should be from your main jar file.

[This](https://dzone.com/articles/generating-executable-jar-file) Link should give you more detail if you are unsure on how to do this. Make sure to edit the manifest file accordingly.

Comment: Let me try it and I will feedback later.

Comment: I try to use eclipse to create the jar file and put the lib folder in the same directory. But the result is still the same. I do not know how to use eclipse to archive the jar file. Do I just can use the JDeveloper? Can I use the eclipse to do the same thing?